# How to document a file that is not in a solution?

Tags: ghostdoc

I have a need to document methods/functions in *.cpp code files that are not part of a .NET solution. Up until now my workaround has been to create a solution, but this is a time consuming step for all the different files I come across.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Scott,

Unfortunately, this is the workaround that you have to use as long as GhostDoc relies on some of the information from Visual Studio CodeDOM... The CodeDOM does not provide *any* info when you open just a single file.

Do you mind me asking if there is particular reason you are opening single file in VS? Other that these might be random files that are not part of a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks srerge, that is exactly right, random files that i want to document. i have projects configured in a completely different IDE targeting NXP Cortex CPUs. it is a bit of trouble to do the work around since it is not a simple matter of dropping a file into an existing solution due to other dependencies. i can live with the workaround though. i like the ghost doc output since it typically gets the documentation correct when i name methods/parameters properly, there tends to be very little that i need to change. kudos to you and the rest of the team.